# show unique links from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that shows a random banner from array:

```
//func.php
function rand_rek($rek_array){
$numberOfBanners = count($rek_array);
$numberOfBanners = $numberOfBanners - 1;
$randomBanner = rand(0,$numberOfBanners);
$rek = $rek_array[$randomBanner];
return $rek;
}
```

I have `$reklamas` array, that contains 3 banners:

```
//ads.php
$reklamas = array($rek1, $rek2, $rek3);
```

if $_GET["noa"] isnt true, I want to add more banners to $reklamas array:

```
if (!isset($_GET["noa"]))
array_push($reklamas, $rek_adc1, $rek_adc2, $rek_adc3, $rek_adc4);
```

And I want to display one of random banners x times:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$banneri;$i++) {
    echo rand_rek($reklamas);
    }
```

The problem:
These can be repeated as many times as they want `array($rek1, $rek2, $rek3);`,
while these `array_push($reklamas, $rek_adc1, $rek_adc2, $rek_adc3, $rek_adc4);` can be each showed only 1 time.

function rand_rek() is in func.php and it is being included from ads.php where is the rest of the code.

Comment: With all chance I haven't understood your question properly, nevertheless check [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). Damn PHP is such a crap, when I look at stuff like `array_push`.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?  You want to have the banner repeated `$banneri` times, unless the banner that is randomly chosen happens to be one of the 4 additional banners?  And I'm guessing you call `rand_rek ($reklamas)`?

Comment: yes @lxop that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably going about the problem all wrong, but in any case a solution could be

```
function rand_rek($rek_array){
    $numberOfBanners = count($rek_array);
    $numberOfBanners = $numberOfBanners - 1;
    $randomBanner = rand(0,$numberOfBanners);
    $rek = $rek_array[$randomBanner];
    return [$randomBanner, $rek];
}

list($bannerNum, $banner) = rand_rek($reklamas);
if ($bannerNum < 3) {
    $repeats = $x;
} else {
    $repeats = 1;
}

for ($i=0;$i<$repeats;$i++) {
    echo $banner;
}
```

Which retrieves the index of the banner and checks it before running the loop.  I've also used your value `$x` that you mention in the text but not in your code.